# Japanese Laptop with Japanese Keyboard Layout

Tags: keyboard, japanese

I have a laptop with Japanese keyboard layout and I want to write portuguese-brazil, how to proceed?

Im running the last version 19.04.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You can use the combination key to type õ or ñ, that's compose key. You can set the compose key on your keyboard for example R_Alt then Compose+~ becomes a dead-key for N or O. Compose + , and C after that you get ç. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key#Common_compose_combinations Alternative way to use Unicode: first press Ctrl + Shift + U and type "00F1" then space, you get ñ, "00D1" you get Ñ.